# Need assistance in converting Makefile to Shell script

Tags: shell, makefile

Need your help to convert code in Makefile to Shell script? Please help as I am new to both MakeFile and Shell Scripting.Thanks.

Sample Code:

```
include Configfile
.PHONY: config-arch asoc-tool clone-repo generate-irx api-login \
    upload-file get-app run-scan show-scan-id get-asset-group create-app

config-arch:
    sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386

asoc-tool: config-arch
    $(eval DIR := $(shell pwd))
    curl -o client.zip $(APPSCAN_TOOL)
    mkdir client ; mkdir tool
    unzip -qq client.zip -d client
    cd client ; ls | xargs -I {} sh -c "cp -r {}/* $(DIR)/tool"
    rm -rf client

clone-repo:
    git clone $(GIT_REPO)

# Generates the irx file for icp-cert-manager.
generate-irx: 
    $(eval DIR := $(shell pwd))

    cd $(PROJECT_NAME); $(DIR)/tool/bin/appscan.sh prepare $(flag)
```

Comment: Why do you want convert? The `make` has many features that shell scripts doesn't support (only with a lot of programming).

Comment: requirement from environment as a shell script for travis integration rather than using Makefile and Configfile.This is for ASoC [appscan on cloud] tool integration with Travis CO so team squads can use and work.Let me know if any further information required.

Let me know

Comment: Oh, understand. Maybe would need `Configfile`. IMHO it's an easy task because all target is PHONY (doesn't produce output) so you need (almost) write the lines by line.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

# config-arch
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386

# asoc-tool
curl -o client.zip $(APPSCAN_TOOL)
mkdir client ; mkdir tool
unzip -qq client.zip -d client
cd client ; ls | xargs -I {} sh -c "cp -r {}/* ./tool"
rm -rf client

# clone repo
git clone ${GIT_REPO} # you should overwrite ${GIT_REPO} to your git repo, maybe from Configfile

# generate-irx
cd $(PROJECT_NAME)
./tool/bin/appscan.sh prepare ${flag} # you should check your ${flag}, maybe from Configfile
```

Comment: Thanks.

I am getting HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length error when I tried to do the curl command

```curl -o token.json -X POST $CONTENT_HEADER_JSON $ACCEPT_HEADER_JSON -d '{"KeyId":$API_KEY, "KeySecret":$SECRET}' $LOGIN_URL

root@31735e6b62d0:/ASocTest# echo $CONTENT_HEADER_JSON
--header 'Content-Type:application/json'
root@31735e6b62d0:/ASocTest# echo $ACCEPT_HEADER_JSON   
--header 'Accept:application/json'
root@31735e6b62d0:/ASocTest#```

Could you please assist?

Comment: I think it's an another question.